# Define global variable with include-path

Tags: php, path, include, require

In my php-project, I want to make sure the code remains portable and server-independet.

So I have added a "config.php" which I include in every php-file, where several config-var's are configured.

I include it with

```
include_once('config.php');
```

My problem is, one of the first vars in this config.php is:

```
global $path;
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

to make all includes / requires absolute and "portable".

This of course works for all includes AFTER the include_once('config.php'); - but how can I make this specific include absolute?

My "solution" for now is this code:

```
//set global path if not yet set
if(!isset($path)){
    global $path;
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
```

which I would add in every php-file.

Is there a more elegant solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is, to use $path as static variable definition like

```
define('PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Then you are able to use the PATH just as a normal variable

```
echo 'directory: '.PATH;
```

Variables are case sensitive, to make them non case-sensitive so that you can use either PATH or path or Path .. add true at the end:

```
define('DOCROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], true);
```

A common use case is for me to shorten DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, true);
```

Regards, Max

Comment: but this would also have to be done in every PHP-file, right?

Comment: nope, you define it once. since your config.inc.php is mandatory you should use require_once('config.php'). On the other side - if you use $path and want to use that variable later in functions or classes - you have to reference them (like global $path; inside every function). But if you define those as static vars, you can access them everywhere globally.

Comment: yeah but please read again above - how would I do require_once('config.php') without actually having the path to this specific file?

Comment: Lol dude that's a infinite loop you got your self into its like saying circular reasoning gets old because circular reasoning gets old because ......... You need to fire your config or a similar script first or a similar script to it on the index page which will givenyou the path to the config

Comment: sure, but I also need to reference some files directly without using index.php... but your solution is the one to use for me because it allows me to also call some special files over CLI

Answer (score 2):

Another way is, to use $path as definition e.g.

```
define('PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Comment: thank you. Do you see any advantages in this? Would you do that on top of each file also?

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine !if there is a better way  I'm not so sure. If your code is dependent on the config.php I suggest using require_once('config.php'); as if the file is not found or included then the script will be terminated causing a fatal error and not continue after that point !

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using php framework.. That's the best solution.. Unless if you want to put it in $_SESSION var but I don't recommend it..

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are realy good way to hell. Using them is most likely the worst thing what can any programmer do. How are you ever going to find it in huge project you see first time and you need to analyze??? Simply you won't. Ctrl+f ok, but still, are you sure you wanna ctrl+f your projects? Plus you usually dont have access to all project files or you just dont have them all on local disc. It is like first lesson on every collage: NEVER USE GLOBAL VARIABLES. Ever heard of static varibales and OOP? That is the way to go. Too bad that PHP won't allow you to assign any variable to constants or even static variables (it amazingly works with static methods - I just tested it - why not static variables then authors?) but DUDE, WHY are u trying to RENAME variables. Since that is all what you are doing. You are renaming variable called '$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']' to another one called 'PATH', ok it is shorter but what is the point of doing that? Shorter != better. $_SERVER is super global already (wich is bad too) but at least those few  superglobals are well known to everyone and I bet authors of PHP can't replace them because people would eat them alive :D (and ofc issues with compability with older versions)